# Экспорт C++ DLL с классом в C# проект (С++ / C#)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

У меня есть **С++ DLL**, в которую вложен класс **с** 4-имя математическими **методами**:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    class __declspec(dllexport) Class_Counter
    {
    public:
        double CountSum(double a, double b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        double CountSubstract(double a, double b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
        double CountDivide(double a, double b)
        {
            return a / b;
        }
        double CountMultiple(double a, double b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    };
}
```

Хотелось бы в **C# Windows Forms** создать объект этого класса, чтобы обратится к методам.
( Либо просто обратится к методам, там как легче).

Здесь главная проблема:

> как импортировать библиотеку **в рабочим состоянии** в С# проект?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: *"класс с 4-имя математическими методами"* - вместо этого бесполезного класса сделайте отдельные функции на С, тогда их можно будет импортировать в c#.

Comment: Здесь дело не в "бесполезных классах", а в решении проблемы импортирования библиотек... Спасибо, про С. Попробую на практике

Comment: Так в C# нельзя импортировать классы или вообще любой код С++, только С функции.

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать

Comment: конечно [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-wrap-native-class-for-use-by-csharp?view=msvc-170) от майкрософт читать вовсе не обязательно

Answer (score 0):

Несмотря на комментарии, импортировать методы из С++ в C# можно, хотя я и очень не рекоммендую так делать. Единственное, надо учитывать что С++ [манглит](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) названия member'ов, так что вам нужно каким-либо образом их узнать. Для этого есть много разных утилит, гуглится это всё по запросу "get exported symbols", дальше дело за малым, пишете обычный PInvoke, не забывая что если метод у экземпляра, то первым параметром идёт this-указатель. На гитхабе есть [проект](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp), который вроде как умеет это делать всё сам, хотя мной он не проверялся, так что ничего не гарантирую.